# bash xprintidle reset inactivity (simulate keystroke or mouse movement)

Tags: bash

Friends,
I'm checking for idle with xprintidle to restart a process:

```
while true; do
    idle=0
    while [ $idle_time -lt $idletime_max ];do
        idle_time=$(xprintidle)
        sleep 1
    done
    # restart process
    # -> process will be restarted right away as system is still idle
done
```

How  do I *reset the system idle timer* xprintidle queries?
Can I simulate a keypress or mouse movement?

TIA!